# Is there something as simple and easy to use as Paint?

Tags: 16.04, paint

Is there a simple and easy app on Ubuntu to do some quick and dirty blocking of say... a license plate in a picture?

I'm hoping that I don't have to install anything, because it's going to long and painful if I do.

Answer (score 2):

[kolourpaint](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/kolourpaint4/) is a nice little image editor. It looks and feels quite similar to ms paint.

Answer (score 1):

Try out MTPaint
[Paint for Linux on SourceForge.net](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net)
It works nicely, also for manipulating small objects, my favorit MsPaint substitute on linux.